# Cognito signUpInBackground callback not called in Kotlin

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm building my sign up form for an Android mobile app in Kotlin with Cognito but I have a problem when I try to actually sign up the user.

In the documentation, we can see this sample Java code to register a user:

```
SignUpHandler signupCallback = new SignUpHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(CognitoUser cognitoUser, boolean userConfirmed, CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails) {
        // Sign-up was successful

        // Check if this user (cognitoUser) needs to be confirmed
        if(!userConfirmed) {
            // This user must be confirmed and a confirmation code was sent to the user
            // cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails will indicate where the confirmation code was sent
            // Get the confirmation code from user
        }
        else {
            // The user has already been confirmed
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
        // Sign-up failed, check exception for the cause
    }
};

userPool.signUpInBackground(userId, password, userAttributes, null, signupCallback);
```

And here's my version in Kotlin:

```
var signupCallback: SignUpHandler = object : SignUpHandler {

    override fun onSuccess(cognitoUser: CognitoUser, userConfirmed: Boolean, cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails: CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails) {
        // Sign-up was successful

        // Check if this user (cognitoUser) needs to be confirmed
        if (!userConfirmed) {
            val intent = Intent(this@RegisterUsernameActivity, ConfirmEmailActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            // This user must be confirmed and a confirmation code was sent to the user
            // cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails will indicate where the confirmation code was sent
            // Get the confirmation code from user
        } else {
            // The user has already been confirmed
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(exception: Exception) {
        // Sign-up failed, check exception for the cause
        Log.d("ERROR", exception.localizedMessage.toString())
    }
}

userPool.signUpInBackground(username, password, userAttributes, null, signupCallback)
```

When I put logs in success and failure cases nothing prints, the callback is just like completely ignored. Do you have any idea of why?

**EDIT:** just tried the Java version just as it's documented and the same problem happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rebooted my computer and it worked...